# Почему ссылка не скрывается?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Пытаюсь сделать, что бы ссылка *Больше* скрывалась если actualHide > visibleHeight, но почему то не срабатывает. Где ошибка?

```js
$(".b-tag__link--more").each(function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  var $content = $link.parent().prev(".b-tag__list");

  // console.log(visibleHeight);

  var visibleHeight = $content[0].clientHeight;
  var actualHide = $content[0].scrollHeight - 1;

  console.log(actualHide);
  console.log(visibleHeight);

  if (actualHide > visibleHeight) {
    $link.show();
  } else {
    $link.hide();
  }
});
$(".b-tag__link--more").on("click", function() {
  var $link = $(this);
  var $content = $link.parent().prev(".b-tag__list");
  var linkText = $link.text();

  $content.toggleClass("short-text full-text");

  $link.text(getShowLinkText(linkText));

  return false;
});

function getShowLinkText(currentText) {
  var newText = '';

  if (currentText.toUpperCase() === "БОЛЬШЕ") {
    newText = "Свернуть";
  } else {
    newText = "Больше";
  }

  return newText;
}
```

```css
.b-tag {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}
.b-tag__list {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.short-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3em;
}
.full-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.b-tag__item {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid@cl-sokolov-table-border;

font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.b-tag__link {
  padding: 13px 12px 12px 12px;
  color: @cl-sokolov-filter-name;

display: block;
  line-height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &: hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
.b-tag__more {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid@cl-sokolov-table-border;

font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-tag">
  <ul class="b-tag__list short-text">
    <li id="1" class="b-tag__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">Gelbgold-Verlobungsringe</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="b-tag__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">Gold-Verlobungsringe</a>
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="b-tag__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">Roségold-Verlobungsringe</a>
    </li>
    <li id="4" class="b-tag__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link">Silber-Verlobungsringe</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="b-tag__more">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="" class="b-tag__link b-tag__link--more">Больше</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/drtvader/x3yx6vzk/1/

Comment: так может прописать if (actualHide > visibleHeight) {
     $link.hide();
    } а то у вас наоборот show()

Comment: Проблема из-за маргинов в `.b-tag__item` они скролл хейгхт распирают поэтому она становится больше клиентской и ссылка показывается

Comment: if (actualHide > visibleHeight) { $link.hide(); }  пробовал, он тогда только скрывает ссылку

Comment: Получается просто маргины убрать надо?

Comment: @drtvader, скорее учитывать их при сравнении

Comment: @Grandy вместо clientHeight использовать offsetHeight ?